# Flutter datetime picker time range

Tags: flutter, datetimepicker

In a datetime picker, I need to show only the 9.00 am to 6.00 pm time range. Is it possible?

[image: DateTime Picker]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible in this package but you can check if the user selected between those two time ranges and give him a warning and tell him to select between given time ranges.

Comment: can you give me an example of how to check that? I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: Yes Let suppose if a user selects a time 5:00 AM, you will be storing that in a variable right. We will check if the time is in between our desired time forexample: `if(selectedTime >= 9:00 || selectedTime <= 18:00) { print("Something");}`. Like that. after this you can show a pop us using a package `flutter_easyloading: ^3.0.3` and executing `EasyLoading.showError("Invalid Time Please Select between 9:00 AM and 6:00 PM");`. I hope this will help :)